# Python round() doesn't round correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just working with Python and encountered an unexpected behaviour. I was using `round()` function to round a random 6-digit integer to the nearest random digit. What I had was something like `round(number, -place)`. So to round 123456 to the nearest tens, I have `round(123456, -1)`, `round(123456, -2)` to round to the nearest hundreds, etc. It worked fine for almost all numbers. The weird problem I spotted was when the number was `485345` rounded to the nearest tens; it'd round it to `485340`. So I tried all sorts of things and found some things out:

- `485344` and `485346` both rounds up/down correctly.
- Trying to round `45` to the nearest tens would give me `40` as well (which is also incorrect)
- Instead of doing `round(number, -1)`, I tried doing `round(number/10)*10`, but it behaves the same way.
- So I tried to round `450` to the nearest hundreds, and it'd give me `400`
- I finally tried rounding `451` to the nearest hundreds, and THEN it gave me the correct answer, `500`
- Same thing with `round(45.1, -1)`, it gives me `50`

This is very weird since when we round 45.1 to the nearest tens, we only look at the ones place and determine whether to round up or down right? So I have to think that there is something going on behind the scenes with the `round()` function that causes this. One solution would be to create my own `round` method, but I was just wondering why this is happening and what would be a good solution by still using the `round()` function?

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: Why is that incorrect?

Comment: Python uses "bankers rounding", it rounds to the even value when halfway between two numbers.